# Time required to visit the Prambanan temple in Indonesia

Tags: planning, indonesia, temples

In july, the day before we will go to Borobudur. Then we have the day for Prambanan (also been recomended Plaosan Temple and Ratu Boko which are close). How long would it take? After that I am headed to Solo and was wondering if I should plan the trip from Yogyakarta to Sola (1 hour on train) for that same day (after dinner or something) or the next day (if I need to stay until late in Prambanan).

EDIT: It is on the 24th of July (I am aware that it will be crowded)

Comment: What jpatokal said - this is just a semi related comment. THE biggest thing 'wrong' with Prambanan is Borobudur. By itself Prambanan would be awesome and impressive. As he said, the site is not large but depending on your degree of interest you could spend 30 minutes to a day, or a lifetime, there. BUT Borobudur is so utterly utterly astoundingly awesome that poor Prambanan does not have a fair chance of competing. I saw it second and it was still very good indeed. But if you had to see one only it would not be the choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say a **few hours** will suffice, it's not that big a site.

I'd actually recommend visiting Prambanan the day *before* going to Borobudur, since it'll still feel impressive that way around.  The best approach is to hit Prambanan in the afternoon, drive up to Borobudur, stay at the [Manohara lodge](http://manoharaborobudur.com/) on the park grounds, and use their sunrise tour package to visit Borobudur one hour before it's opened to the general public.

That said, Prambanan is on the way from Borobudur to Solo (Surakarta), so logistically it may be more straightforward to cover on your way out.